# Web Scraping HTML page using PowerShell - loop DIV and export result as table

Tags: html, powershell

I try to scrape an HTML page using PS. I want to retrieve a specific DIV class attrs
Here is my code.

```
    $url = 'https://www.besoccer.com/competition/1_division_belarus'
$req =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get

if ($req.StatusCode -ne 200) {
    Write-Warning "Error: Website returned statuscode $($req.StatusCode)"
}
else {
          $date = ($req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.classname -eq 'date-transform date ta-c'}).innerHTML
          $date += ($req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.classname -eq 'match-status-label'}).InnerText
          $homet = ($req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.classname -match 'team-name ta-r team_left'}).InnerText
          $homea = ($req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.classname -match 'team-name ta-l team_right'}).InnerText
          $res = [pscustomobject]@{
    Date = $($date)
    Time = $($time)
    Home = $($homet)
    Away = $($homea)
}
#$res
}
$res
```

But I receive the following result

```
Date                                                    Time Home                                                    Away                                                  
----                                                    ---- ----                                                    ----                                                  
{20 MAY 2022, 21 MAY 2022, 22 May 2022, 22 May 2022...}      {Baranovichi, FK Smorgon, Dnepr Rogachev, FC Slonim...} {Volna Pinsk, Osipovichy, Naftan Novopolotsk, Lokom...
```

How can I receive data as table (format-table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse `DIV` class inside each event e.g. as follows:

```
$url = 'https://www.besoccer.com/competition/1_division_belarus'
$req =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get

if ($req.StatusCode -ne 200) {
    Write-Warning "Error: Website returned statuscode $($req.StatusCode)"
} else {
    $Events = $req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('a') |
        Where-Object {$_.id -match "^match-"}
    $res = foreach ($Event in $Events) {
        $date  = ($Event.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.classname -eq 'date-transform date ta-c'}).innerHTML
        $time  = ($Event.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.classname -eq 'match-status-label'}).InnerText
        $homet = ($Event.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.classname -match 'team-name ta-r team_left'}).InnerText
        $homea = ($Event.getElementsByTagName('div') | where {$_.classname -match 'team-name ta-l team_right'}).InnerText
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Date = $date
            Time = $time
            Home = $homet
            Away = $homea
        }
    }
    $res
}
```

**Output**: `.\SO\72332736.ps1`

```
Date        Time Home           Away              
----        ---- ----           ----              
20 MAY 2022 End  Baranovichi    Volna Pinsk       
21 MAY 2022 End  FK Smorgon     Osipovichy        
22 MAY 2022 End  Dnepr Rogachev Naftan Novopolotsk
22 MAY 2022 End  FC Slonim      Lokomotiv Gomel   
22 MAY 2022 End  Molodechno     Shakhtyor Petrikov
22 MAY 2022 End  Ostrovets      FK Lida
```